# Using threads in a solution in c# for IO

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, arduino

I'm currently busy writing some c# code to interface with an Arduino. The code periodically samples audio and transmits data to physically represent the audio levels. I've created a WPF interface for this program, but I pretty much am at a dead end with the final steps. In my interface i would like to be able to change parameters for what is being transmitted as well as displaying feedback read from the COM port.

I don't really understand how to properly make threads in c# - I can imagine how you would create a separate process to manage the IO here as the COM port can only be operated on by a simple process. How would i simultaneously run a loop to sample my audio and send it and another loop to read the serial port, all while still remaining separated from the WPF process so the UI doesn't freeze.

Any tips about proper practice to create these threads securely and efficiently is massively appreciated too!

Thanks

Comment: Can this not be done with TAP instead?

Comment: ^^ [Task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) Someone not even sure about how to use Threads will probably struggle with a random 3LA thrown at him, @CaiusJard ;P (see what I did there? Stay healthy, friends ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest model is to use a few separate [Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8).  Each thread runs in an infinite loop, which is defined in a method called a TreadProc, and so each Thread is like a seperate program, but it runs in the same Process and can interact directly with the UI.

These background threads can interact with the WPF UI through the UI Elements' dispatchers.  See [Threading Model - WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!